# Is depth between any two leaf node in binary tree greater than one

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I've been working on this coding problem and have been able to successfully get the depth of each leaf node into a hash set. What I'm trying to do is determine if the difference in depth is of a leaf node is greater than one BEFORE that depth is added to the hash set. I don't want to put all of the leaf nodes in the hash set and use two for loops to check if there is a difference in depth greater than one. In my code below, the int variable count represents depth.

The problem is my code always returns true. Something is wrong with the code where is checks the difference in depths/count for each leaf node. Code is below. I'm trying to keep this method in O(n) time, and avoid O(n^2).

The depths of the four leaf nodes in this tree are : 3, 2, 2, 5

```
import java.util.*;
public class cakeEightWeekly {
 static int count = 0;
 public static class Node {
  public int value;
  public Node leftChild;
  public Node rightChild;
  public Node(int value) {
   this.value = value;
  }
  public void setLeft(Node leftValue) {
   this.leftChild = leftValue;
  }
  public void setRight(Node rightValue) {
   this.rightChild = rightValue;
  }
  public Node getRight() {
   return rightChild;
  }
  public Node getLeft() {
   return leftChild;
  }
 }
 public static boolean isBalanced(Node root) {
  HashSet < Integer > hset = new HashSet < Integer > ();
  if (root != null) {
   count++;
   isBalanced(root.getLeft());
   isBalanced(root.getRight());
   count--;
   if (root.getLeft() == null && root.getRight() == null) {
    if (!hset.isEmpty()) {
     for (int x: hset) {
      if ((x - count) < 0) {
       int sum = count - x;
       if (sum > 1) {
        return false;
       }
      } else if ((x - count) > 1) {
       return false;
      }
     }
     hset.add(count);
    } else {
     hset.add(count);
    }
   }
  }
  return true;
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Node One = new Node(1);
  Node Two = new Node(2);
  Node Three = new Node(3);
  Node Four = new Node(4);
  Node Five = new Node(5);
  Node Six = new Node(6);
  Node Seven = new Node(7);
  Node Eight = new Node(8);
  Node Nine = new Node(9);
  Node Ten = new Node(10);
  Node Eleven = new Node(11);
  Five.setLeft(Three);
  Five.setRight(Seven);
  Three.setLeft(Two);
  Three.setRight(Four);
  Two.setLeft(One);
  Seven.setLeft(Six);
  Seven.setRight(Eight);
  Eight.setRight(Nine);
  Nine.setRight(Ten);
  Ten.setRight(Eleven);
  System.out.print(isBalanced(Five));
 }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just keep track of min and max depth so far in visited leaves? Any time max - min > 1, return true (or false, depending upon the case).

Comment: if you'd like an answer that addresses your recursive solution, please fix your code formatting to use consistent alignment and tight spacing

Comment: `determine if the difference in depth is of a leaf node is greater than one BEFORE that depth is added to the hash set.` I fail to fully parse that sentence: what does the `is of a leaf node`-part mean? Is it *determine if the difference in depth of a leaf node to any leaf node handled before is greater than one …*? I see you adding a depth for *every* node: where should *leaf* make a difference?

Comment: `I see you adding a depth for every node` which, while contra-factual, was partially due to excessive nesting and minimalistic indentation: fix that.

Comment: You don't use the results of `isBalanced(root.getLeft())` & `isBalanced(root.getRight())`. You use a `Set` - which is overkill as displayName points out - but create a new one for every call of `isBalanced()` (which might better be a method member of `Node`). Don't use/manipulate a ("global"/"tree") variable named `count`: that is a *depth* or *level*: pass it as a parameter.